# In QGIS how do I filter layer so just one of the features in that layer displays and all others are not displayed?

Tags: filter

I have a simple shapefile polygon layer that I would like to just have it display only one of the polygons temporarily and have all other polygons not displayed.

How can I do this applying some sort of filter?

I have had to create a separate shapefile of the polygon I want to display and use it as a separate layer every time I need to do this, but I am sure there is a better way. I am using 3.12.

Comment: Add an ID to your features and then use the [filter function](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/basic_analysis.html?highlight=filter#basic-fa-start-a-project-and-get-the-data).

Answer (score 1):

If your polygons have a unique attribute you can use the query builder to only display that polygon.  [See here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/query_builder.html) for more help using the query builder.

Comment: Please refer to up-to-date documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this, sounds a bit complicated, I was looking for a simpler way...think the other responses have solved it, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the polygon and copy and paste it into your project as a temporary scratch layer.  Another option for special circumstances is to set the layer symbology to no brush/no pen and then only a selected polygon will be displayed.  You can adjust how a selected polygon looks in the settings or properties.  The ultimate in temporary is to use the no brush/pen symbology and use the Edit - Select by value form to "select" a record but instead of selecting it use the flash feature to see it.

Comment: I'll add that for very temporary visual use you can uncheck the layer so it isn't visible but keep it active and then use the i button to see the shape temporarily.

Comment: Thanks Erik, very useful response, I will use any and all of those ways.